# Deserialize complex JSON using Alamofire and Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

How can I deserialize this JSON and display the titles in a tableView
JSON: https://www.healthcare.gov/api/articles.json

What I have tried so far:

```
struct  News {
    let title : String

    init(dictionary: [String:String]) {
        self.title = dictionary["mainTitle"] ?? ""
    }
}

var newsData = [News]()

func downloadData() {
    Alamofire.request("https://www.healthcare.gov/api/articles.json").responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request as Any)
        print(response.response as Any)
        print(response.data as Any)
        print(response.result.value)

        self.newsData.removeAll()
        if let json = response.result.value as? [[String:String]] {
            for news in json {
                self.newsData.append(News(dictionary: news))
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
      downloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newsData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let news = newsData[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = news.title
    return cell
}
```

The server status code is 200 so I know that my request is ok. The thing is that I do not know how can I create a proper data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is confusing because at the end of the `articles` array – which is supposed to contain only dictionaries – there is a single boolean `false` so downcast to `[[String:Any]]` fails.

You have to `flatMap` the array to ignore the `Bool`

```
    if let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any],
       let articles = json["articles"] as? [Any] {
           for news in articles.flatMap({$0 as? [String:Any]}) {
               self.newsData.append(News(dictionary: news))
           }
           self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

and the key `mainTitle` does not exist in the JSON, in the `init` method of `News` you have to write (the dictionary is `[String:Any]` rather than `[string:String]`)

```
init(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
    self.title = dictionary["title"] ?? ""
}
```

Comment: What did you mean with parsedData, it does not exist but you assigned it to articles, the compiler wont let me run it.

Comment: But now my app crashes because there is a nil while unwrapping on this line
        self.newsData.append(News(dictionary: news as! [String : String] ))

Comment: The dictionary is `[String:Any]`. I updated the answer. And remove the forced downcast.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with JSON in swift I recommend you to use SwiftyJSON. (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

```
var myJson : JSON
func downloadData() {
    Alamofire.request("https://www.healthcare.gov/api/articles.json").responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request as Any)
        print(response.response as Any)
        print(response.data as Any)
        print(response.result.value)
        self.myJson = JSON(response.result.value)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

now you can iterate through `myJson` and adapt `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` to retrieve your result

Comment: But how can I extract just title? Also you are assigning response.result which has no JSON information, it only has server headers. The JSON can be found under response.result.value, but I do not need to iterate through the whole array, I just need titles.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function with this one.

```
func downloadData() {
            Alamofire.request("https://www.healthcare.gov/api/articles.json").responseJSON { response in
                print(response.request as Any)
                print(response.response as Any)
                print(response.data as Any)
                print(response.result.value)

                self.newsData.removeAll()
                if let json = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject]  //As outermost object in your JSON file is a dictionary
                {
                    let article = json["articles"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] //Here you need to get inner object which is value for key "articles"
                    for news in article {
                        self.newsData.append(News(dictionary: news))
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
```

You can get readable JSON at http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try to map your response to a data model. Then you need not deserialize your json. [https://github.com/insanoid/SwiftyJSONAccelerator](http://SwiftyJSONAccelerator) will help you create your data model.

Comment: You say `Try to map your response to a data model.` But OP is already saying "The thing is that I do not know how can I create a proper data model". They already know they should do this. They're asking *how* to do it.